# Fail2Ban - Log to mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, security

We have a few servers with SSH public (using sFTP).
Obviously, the attacks ar too many.

We want put the banned logs into a MySQL DB for make stats and etc.

Have anyone tryied this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Fail2SQL - An SQL logger for Fail2Ban](http://fail2sql.sourceforge.net/)

Fail2SQL is called by Fail2Ban and logs information to a MySQL database including geographical location and total ban count. This information can then be used in reports, graphs or by third party programs to take further action such as permanent blocking, reporting to ISP etc.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be no direct way to do this. You will have to write a script to parse the fail2ban logfiles and insert IP's and bantimes into a mysql table. I found one here: http://blog.dp.cx/25/postfix-fail2ban-win